# How to show a component inside dialog box in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I couldn't find any feature or library in the internet that support dialog box in React Native. Is there any way or do I have to use Android native dialog box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the **native** android/ios dialog boxes, you **cannot** show a component inside of it. However, you can design your own customised dialog box using the **React Native Modal** component or, alternatively, you can use a **third-party library** that allows this, such as:
[React Native Pop-up Dialog](https://github.com/jacklam718/react-native-popup-dialog)

Comment: Thanks I prefer using that library , I'm wondering why I couldn't find this library during last two days :)

Comment: Cool! I'm glad I helped.